# ggplot wont show confidence intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data-frame `df` in long format (several observations for each year). I want to plot the average of the variable `length` for each year across years with confidence intervals. I use this code:

```
ggplot(df[df$year>2004,],aes(x=year, y=length)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "smooth") +
    xlab("") + ylab("Report Length") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2005, max(df$year), by = 2))
```

The last time I ran this code it gave me the exact graph I want: [image: What I want], but this time the confidence interval does not show up: [image: What I get] I did not change the code, but I did update all the packages and now I can't get the confidence intervals.

Comment: I think you'll get them adding `se = TRUE`.  As far as I know this the default, so I'm not sure why it doesn't show up without that.

Comment: Is data the same?

Comment: @ aosmith Thank you, it did solve the problem! @ PoGibas Yes, the data are the same. However, the data are not exactly the same between the plots I posted here because the 1st plot was done when I manipulated the length variable (hence difference in y axis), but it was the only plot i had left from the last successful run with CIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `se = TRUE`, as suggested by @aosmith, solved the problem. The code now looks like this:

```
ggplot(df[df$year>2004,],aes(x=year, y=length)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", geom = "smooth", se = TRUE) +
    xlab("") + ylab("Report Length") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(2005, max(df$year), by = 2))
```

It remains unclear why it worked earlier without specifying `se = TRUE` and does not work now.

Comment: Looks like this was changed in the [fix](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2567) to [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1546), where `stat_summary` defaults to `se = FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you for this information @aosmith, this clarifies everything.